# Apache .htaccess redirecting https to http and vice versa

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to get a drupal 7 install to redirect three pages to https and force everything else back to http.
In isolation, the first rewrite rule here works. With both enabled, nothing works and it all redirects back to /index.php

```
# Turn SSL on for checkout except for checkout, signup/login and user/login
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/checkout)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/signup\/login)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/user\/login)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Turn SSL off everything but checkout, signup/login and user/login
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(checkout|signup\/login|user\/login) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? You might want to post it here, I'm stuck too on the same problem.

Comment: I'm thinking it has to do with how Drupal handles URL, but I'm really not sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct and the rules work for me. Since the first rule works I'll assume `RewriteEngine on` is somewhere above these rules. Are there other rules in your htaccess files? Could be something else causing the issue.

I tried the following rules and am redirected as expected by both of them. The absence of the HTTPS rule shouldn't make a difference.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Turn SSL on for checkout except for checkout, signup/login and user/login
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/checkout)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/signup\/login)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/user\/login)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ssl/$1 [R=301,L]

# Turn SSL off everything but checkout, signup/login and user/login
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(checkout|signup\/login|user\/login) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ssl/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I setup these files to test with:

- public/

  - checkout   (contents: checkout)
  - foobar     (contents: foobar)
  - signup/

    - login    (contents: signup/login)
  - user/

    - login    (contents: user/login)
  - ssl/

    - checkout (contents: ssl checkout)
    - foobar   (contents: ssl foobar)
    - signup/

      - login  (contents: ssl signup/login)
    - user/

      - login  (contents: ssl user/login)

You can try these rules out and see they work as expected:

```
$ curl -L http://samhuri.net/checkout
ssl checkout
$ curl -L http://samhuri.net/ssl/checkout
ssl checkout
$ curl -L http://samhuri.net/foobar
foobar
$ curl -L http://samhuri.net/ssl/foobar
foobar
```

Pass `curl` the `-i` flag to see headers and status codes.

So I suspect something else is awry. Do you have any other rules to redirect to or from https?